# How to replace one specific line of many files from one instruction file in batches?

Tags: bash

We hope to replace the Line 3 of file001 to file600 with corresponding line in the instruction.txt, and is there any possible solution in bash language? I thought maybe I could write a script with `sed` or `awk` command, but I couldn't come up with it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The file001 to file600 contain many cartesian coordinates and are of the same format. E.g. file001 is as follows:

```
3.02  5.46  8.94
4.55  3.22  4.35
0.00  0.00  0.00 # this is the wrong line and we want to get it replaced
2.34  3.32  5.47
...
```

The instruction.txt file is:

```
file001
3.25  1.13  6.10  #this means to replace the 3rd line of "file001" with "3.25  1.13  6.10"
file002
6.01  1.17  -0.32  #this means to replace the 3rd line of "file002" with "6.01  1.17  -0.32"
...
```

Comment: Modifying files "inplace" with `awk` or `sed` is not standard and differs from OS to OS. Is it for Linux?

Comment: `this is the wrong line` How do you know it's "wrong"? `this means to replace the 3rd line` Is it always the 3rd line?

Comment: How is the wrong line determined? Is it always the third line? Or a line containing exactly `0.00 0.00 0.00`?

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment! Yes, it is always the 3rd line. Cuz this line represents a coordinate and was previously calculated faulty. So we recalculated and got the correct coordinates of line 3 in a new instruction.txt.

Comment: Yes, later the 600 files are for Linux. So whatever the instruction.txt filetype would be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution look pretty messed up, but it works :) you can try it, let me know if it works for you.

```
for i in `cat instruction.txt | awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { printf $0; printf "\n" }'`; do
        outp=`awk '/'"$i"'/{getline; print}' instruction.txt`;
        sed -i '3s/0.00  0.00  0.00/'"$outp"'/' $i;
done
```

First, I try to filter all the odd lines that contain filename, and assign it to the variable `$i`:

```
cat instruction.txt | awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { printf $0; printf "\n" }'
```

Then get the next line of every `$i`, which is fix value and assign it to the variable `$outp`:

```
outp=`awk '/'"$i"'/{getline; print}' instruction.txt`
```

And finally, replace the wrong 3rd line with 2 variables I just received.

```
sed -i '3s/0.00  0.00  0.00/'"$outp"'/' $i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r line; do 
  if [[ $(sed -E 's/^([^ ]*).*/\1/' <<< "$line") =~ "file" ]]; then 
    file=$line
  elif [[ $(sed -E 's/^([^ ]*).*/\1/' <<< "$line") =~ [0-9.] ]]; then 
    sed -i.bak "3c$line" "$file"
  fi
done < instructions.txt
```

Comment: @Rabbiiiiit Great! Please also be aware this creates backup files as it modifies the files in case there is a need to rollback. Be sure to clean up after if used. The files will have `.bak` extension

Comment: I see that when executing~ that's a kind reminder